# How do I remove a part of an URL using regex in Python?

Tags: python

I have an a list of URL that looks like this:

'https://www.superpopgadget.com/collections/best-sellers/products/sushi-roll-bazooka?Ffbclid=IwAR3WfVizYJF0RCP2AsSoulLjJK2_OUwQZ0Y1eep_b3Einm1XNJbcF_K3wYI'

I wanna scrape it to just get: 
'https://www.superpopgadget.com/collections/best-sellers/products/sushi-roll-bazooka'

Comment: you can just split it on `?` character if that is always your problem in the url

Comment: Just use `split('?')[0]`. Split examples cam be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).

Comment: `re.sub("\?.*","",url)`

Comment: You should really use a url parser, eg the built-in https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is any other more efficient method but this might work fine:

`(.+)\?(.+)`

It matches in the first group everything before the character `?` and the second group is everything after it. What you need is the first group.

[Example in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PGwDNL/1)